# How to get confidence of model prediction in python & sklearn.svm.SVC?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have created a support vector model which makes a prediction via `model.predict()`. Is there a way to see the probability or confidence of this prediction?

```
def svc_training(X, y):
    # Create a support vector classifier
    clf = SVC(C=1)
    # Fit the classifier using the training data
    clf.fit(X, y)
    return clf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable [probability](http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) parameter:

> probability: boolean, optional (default=False) :
>
> Whether to enable probability estimates. This must be enabled prior to
> calling fit, and will slow down that method.

So, `clf = SVC(C=1, probability=True)` and you can reach confidence scores with

```
predictions = model.predict(predict_df)
clf.predict_proba(predict_df)
```

where `predict_df` is simply the dataframe you want to predict.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SVC.predict_proba(X)`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.predict_proba) But you need to set `probability=True` when you create a instance of `SVC`.
You can read in [`doc`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.predict_proba) of `SVC.predict_proba(X)`:

> Compute probabilities of possible outcomes for samples in X.
> The model need to have probability information computed at training time: fit with attribute probability **set to True**.

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC

def svc_training(X, y):
    # Create a support vector classifier
    clf = SVC(C=1, probability=True)
    # Fit the classifier using the training data
    clf.fit(X, y)
    return clf

X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [1, 1], [2, 1]])
y = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1])
clf = svc_training(X,y)

print(clf.predict([[-0.8, -1]]))
# [0]

print(clf.predict_proba([[-0.8, -1]]))
# [[0.8656444 0.1343556]]
# probability of '0' is 0.8656444
# probability of '1' is 0.1343556

print(clf.predict([[1, , 1.5]]))
# [1]

print(clf.predict_proba([[1, 1.5]]))
# [[0.12552049 0.87447951]]
# probability of '0' is 0.12552049
# probability of '1' is 0.87447951
```